# Understanding a polyfill for JavaScript CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() method for Internet Explorer 5-8

Tags: javascript

On Mozilla's MDN WebDocs site there is an example of the polyfill for the CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() method for Internet Explorer 5-8:

According to the origin:

> The below polyfill will correct the input of the arguments of
>   insertRule() to standardize them in Internet Explorer 5–8. It
>   supplements insertRule() with a function that separates the selector
>   from the rules before sending the arguments to the default native
>   insertRule().

Here is the code for that polyfill:

```
(function(Sheet_proto){
  var originalInsertRule = Sheet_proto.insertRule;

  if (originalInsertRule.length === 2){ // 2 mandatory arguments: (selector, rules)
    Sheet_proto.insertRule = function(selectorAndRule){
      // First, separate the selector from the rule
      a: for (var i=0, Len=selectorAndRule.length, isEscaped=0, newCharCode=0; i !== Len; ++i) {
        newCharCode = selectorAndRule.charCodeAt(i);
        if (!isEscaped && (newCharCode === 123)) { // 123 = "{".charCodeAt(0)
          // Secondly, find the last closing bracket
          var openBracketPos = i, closeBracketPos = -1;

          for (; i !== Len; ++i) {
            newCharCode = selectorAndRule.charCodeAt(i);
            if (!isEscaped && (newCharCode === 125)) { // 125 = "}".charCodeAt(0)
              closeBracketPos = i;
            }
            isEscaped ^= newCharCode===92?1:isEscaped; // 92 = "\\".charCodeAt(0)
          }

          if (closeBracketPos === -1) break a; // No closing bracket was found!
            /*else*/ return originalInsertRule.call(
            this, // the sheet to be changed
            selectorAndRule.substring(0, openBracketPos), // The selector
            selectorAndRule.substring(closeBracketPos), // The rule
            arguments[3] // The insert index
          );
        }

        // Works by if the char code is a backslash, then isEscaped
        // gets flipped (XOR-ed by 1), and if it is not a backslash
        // then isEscaped gets XORed by itself, zeroing it
        isEscaped ^= newCharCode===92?1:isEscaped; // 92 = "\\".charCodeAt(0)
      }
      // Else, there is no unescaped bracket
      return originalInsertRule.call(this, selectorAndRule, "", arguments[2]);
    };
  }
})(CSSStyleSheet.prototype);
```

You can find it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

Let's assume we have an Internet Explorer of version below 9, and we're trying to call insertRule() like this: `insertRule('h1 { color: white }', 0)`. I am trying to understand several lines of code from this polyfill.

1. As I understand, the value of
   `selectorAndRule.substring(closeBracketPos)` should represent the
   rule `color: white`, but I think the value will be just `}` because `}` is
   the last character in `selectorAndRule` and `closeBracketPos` will
   equal `selectorAndRule.length - 1`, so the `subsring()` method will
   start working from the end of the `selectorAndRule`.
2. The value of `arguments[3]` should represent the insert index (in
   our case `0`), but I think it will be `undefined` because we call
   `insertRule()` with 2 arguments and thus we only  have access to
   `arguments[0]` (which equals `'h1 { color: white }'`) and
   `arguments[1]` (which equals `0`).
3. If we call insertRule without brackets, for example:
   `insertRule('@charset "utf-8"', 5)`, the value of `arguments[2]` in
   `originalInsertRule.call(this, selectorAndRule, "", arguments[2])`
   should be `5`. But will be `undefined`. Or no?

Comment: Genuine question: why would we assume this? Microsoft killed off every version of IE up to and including 8 in January of 2016, with IE9 and IE10 having since joined them. Only IE11 is covered by official support. But even if they weren't dead, rather than shimming Javascript, why not just have dedicated IE8 and below stylesheets, included with IE conditional comment syntax, so that what you need loaded gets loaded in those obsolete browsers?

Comment: Companies can have legacy applications they never managed to upgrade and that rely on old IE versions. @Mike

Comment: Right, so: all those IE versions support conditional CSS comments, so why shim things on the JS side? (especially as this is not a function that people usually rely on)

Comment: I understand the code like you. They probably meant for 1 `selectorAndRule.substring(openBracketPos, closeBracketPos)`, and for both 2 and 3 `arguments[1]`. But you are the one with a IE 5 at hand to debug it, right? Have fun!

Comment: I know that IE of versions 5-8 is dead, so the question is not about how to do things for IE but rather about whether I don't understand the code correctly or there is a mistake on Mozilla's WebDocs site. @Mike

Comment: This is one of those cases where you want to load this in the browser, call it, and have a `debugger` statement at the start of the function: then step through it. The browser's debugger gives you full inspection of which currently variables contain which values, and you can, per line, see _exactly_ what happens. No answer by someone here can give you the level of detail that dev tools will already give you on your own computer.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger for more information on how to use your built-in debugger. They are _incredibly_ valuable tools for both figuring out problems, but also for learning what some code does.